# Access get request in express with middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

Is there any way to access the request object that is sent to any route without accessing it in a .get or something like that but instead access any request sent to express globally?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do. You cannot access any request globally, because a request object is not a global object. Why do you want to access it globally and not in a middleware?

Comment: I don't have access to individual routes in my program because i'm using a library which plugs into express and sets up routes itself. So I want to access requests globally

Comment: If you register a middleware to you application right before any other middleware, then this one will be called first, and you can access the request and response object for every request there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's the most of the point of middleware.

Quoting from [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html):

> ```
> var requestTime = function (req, res, next) {
>   req.requestTime = Date.now()
>   next()
> }
>
> app.use(requestTime)
> ```

Comment: Okay, I tried this   var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
    context.log.log('LOGGED')
    next()
  }
  
  expressApp.use(myLogger) and it doesn't work

Comment: @kumail if it is the first middleware that is registered to the `expressApp` then it has to work. They are called in the order they are registered.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I figured it out, it needed to be registered before the other stuff